# Is it possible to bind domain name to URL address?

Tags: dns, hosting

Is it possible to make different domains point to main "parent" domain but on different pages?
For example now I have main domain "site.com" with different language versions like site.com/en, site.com/fr and etc. Can I point other domains for this versions? e.g. point site.fr to site.com/fr?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to own all of the sites domains.

For example: If you own the `site.fr` domain, you can redirect that to `site.com/fr`.